# Solving: $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-2i\pi xy-\pi x^2/r^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I would like to solve:$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-2i\pi xy-\pi x^2/r^2}dx$$

Where $i$ is the imaginary unit, and $y,r$ are constants.
I've used Wolfram to get $re^{-\pi r^2 y ^2}$. Any way of solving it step-by-step?

Comment: By following his solution I get the answer $re^{-r^2x^2/(2\pi)}$, with $\beta=\pi /r^2$ in his $G_{\beta}(\omega)$. Which is not the answer I have. Or perhaps I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Nevermind I found it: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierTransformGaussian.html Thank you it helped a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call this function $f(y)$ so $f(0)=r$ from the usual Gaussian integral. We need only show $f'(y)=-2\pi r^2 y f(y)$. Integrating by parts, $$f'(y)=-2\pi i\int_\mathbb{R}x\exp(-2\pi ixy-\frac{\pi x^2}{r^2})dx=-2\pi r^2y\int_\mathbb{R}\exp(-2\pi ixy-\frac{\pi x^2}{r^2})dx.$$

Comment: what do you mean by "Call this function" $f(y)$? You mean the whole integral? And y is a constant. Are you making it a variable?

Comment: @Maximus That's exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: I understand that part but why is it only necessary to show that "$f'(y)=-2\pi r^2 y f(y)$" I am confused how this gives the original solution.

Comment: Because the desired result is the unique solution to that differential equation satisfying $f(0)=r$.

Comment: Ah I see, I found a simpler answer which is what you are saying as well: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierTransformGaussian.html